# C - pointers, arrays and strings

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

1. Why is it important to reserve enough space for an extra character when declaring/allocating a string?
2. What happens when one tries to dereference a pointer to NULL?
3. What is wrong with the following code below?

int n = 5;

int array[n];

int i = 3;

array[n] = i;

Comment: Are these questions from an assignment or test?

Comment: What research have you carried out into these questions? Did you try searching on Stack Overflow or using a search engine? What did you find?

Comment: You should just run the code to figure this out yourself.

Comment: "What happens when one tries to dereference a pointer to NULL?" *Undefined behaviour*, which usually translates to *bad things*.

Comment: What is a "pointer to NULL" anyway? Is that a double pointer?

Comment: Please do not change your question so that answers you've gotten becomes unusable. If you have more questions, just post new separate questions.

Answer (score 2):

1. Because strings are null terminated, meaning that there's a `\0` character last in the string to tell functions reading the string where the string ends.
2. What happens is that your program will have undefined behavior and could do pretty much anything. It'll most probably crash.
3. You are trying to declare a VLA (variable length array) at file scope. It needs to be in a function. Also, `array[n] = i;` accesses the array out of bounds since the array only has `n` elements.

Comment: _"Because strings are usually null terminated,..."_ Aren't strings null-terminated by definition?

Comment: @adabsurdum When people talk about strings, they usually mean null terminated strings, but you could have strings with the length first and the data following the length etc if you'd like. You'd have to create your own printing functions etc. for them though.

Comment: I see what you mean; of course one can implement their own string representation as you suggest. I was thinking of ["a string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1p1) But that is from the Standard Library, and I suppose a freestanding implementation isn't required to follow this.

Comment: @adabsurdum Ah, yes, good point. I didn't think that was defined in the standard, but it is, even in the C23 draft. I removed _"usually"_.